# Are the SpaceX ground crew wearing masks as part of a standard suit or to prevent COVID-19?

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2, operations, ground-crew

Watching the live SpaceX operations and I noticed the ground crew were all wearing masks

[image: Ground crew masks]

Is this part of the standard ground crew kit, or is this just for COVID-19 prevention?

Comment: The hair nets are normal for avoiding weird FOD crap in the capsule. I think they used masks for similar reasons in the past, but Covid is definitly part of it.

Comment: I think we should call them "ninjas", not pad crew.

Comment: There are plenty of pictures of Mercury/Gemini/Apollo crew being loaded by pad crew with hairnets and without masks.  Guenter Wendt was notorious about everything being absolutely perfect, yet he did not wear a mask.